# How can i make component accepts elements inside?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to make a component but i want that one accepts elements too. For example :

Component :

```js
const Example = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            //Some Elements will come here.
        </div>
    )
}
```

Another Page :

```js
const App = () => {

    return (
        <Example>
            <div>
                <h1>Hello all </h1>
                <p>I want that elements acceptable on my custom component </p>
            </div>
        </Example>
    )
}
```

But i only can send props and i cant write anything inside of tags of my component. How can i make it ? Thanks for all!

Comment: What do you mean by _"i cant write anything inside of tags of my component"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React defined a special prop called `children`. That's what you exacly need.

Try like this

```
const Example = ({ children }) => {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Example>
            <div>
                <h1>Hello all </h1>
                <p>I want that elements acceptable on my custom component </p>
            </div>
        </Example>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [props.children](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

```
const Example = props => {
    return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you !! Its helped me a lot.